# Calling another function inside gen server call's handle_call waits and shows a timeout error in Erlang OTP

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I'm trying to send and receive messages through a **chat_server**. I start chat users by calling start_link in **chat_client**.Let's say chat server is Alice, then chat clients are Bob and Clark. I have created **'send_message'** and **'receive_message'** functions inside chat_client and added gen server calls for them. Then I created **'send_message_server'** and **'receive_message_server'** functions in chat_server and added gen server calls for them also. In here what I tried is, every send_message function from a client side will go through send_message_server function in chat server (same happens in receiving also).**'send_message' and 'receive_message' works fine seperately with the chat server. But, when I include the receive_message() function inside the send_message() function, it will make a waiting time and shows me a timeout error.**

chat_server code:

```
-module(chat_server).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/0, send_message_server/3, receive_message_server/3, stop/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2,
  code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(chat_server_state, {messages,receivers,senders,sent,received}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Spawning and gen_server implementation
%%%===================================================================

start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

send_message_server(From,To,Msg)->
  io:format("message sent!~n"),
  gen_server:call({?MODULE,'alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV'}, {send_message_server,From,To,Msg}).

receive_message_server(From,To,Msg)->
  io:format("message received!~n"),
  gen_server:call({?MODULE,'alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV'}, {receive_message_server,From,To,Msg}).

stop() ->
  gen_server:stop(?MODULE).

init([]) ->
  io:format("~p starting...",[?MODULE]),
  {ok, #chat_server_state{
    messages = [],
    sent=[],
    received = [],
    receivers = [],
    senders=[]
  }}.

handle_call({send_message_server,From,To,Msg}, _From, State = #chat_server_state{receivers = Receivers,messages = Messages, sent =Sent, senders = Senders}) ->
  io:format("message came to server and then conveyed by the server~n"),
  {reply, ok, State#chat_server_state{receivers = [To|Receivers], messages = [Msg|Messages], sent=[Msg|Sent], senders = [From|Senders]}};

handle_call({receive_message_server,From,To,Msg}, _From, State = #chat_server_state{received = Received }) ->
  io:format("A message sent by ~p, it received to ~p~n",[From,To]),
  {reply, ok, State#chat_server_state{received = [Msg|Received]}}.


handle_cast(_Request, State = #chat_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State = #chat_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State = #chat_server_state{}) ->
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State = #chat_server_state{}, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.
```

chat_client code:

```
-module(chat_client).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/0, stop/0, send_message/3, receive_message/3]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2,
  code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(chat_server_state, {messages,receivers,senders,sent,received}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Spawning and gen_server implementation
%%%===================================================================

start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

send_message(From,To, Msg)->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, node()},{send_message,From,To,Msg}).

receive_message(From, To, Msg)->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, list_to_atom(To)},{receive_message,From,To,Msg}).

stop()->
  gen_server:stop(?MODULE).

init([]) ->
  io:format("~p connected...",[node()]),
  {ok, #chat_server_state{
    messages = [],
    sent=[],
    received = [],
    receivers = [],
    senders = []
  }}.

handle_call({send_message,From,To,Msg}, _From, State = #chat_server_state{receivers = Receivers,messages = Messages, sent =Sent, senders = Senders}) ->
  chat_server:send_message_server(From,To,Msg),
%%  receive_message(From,To,Msg), //when I add this line I get the waiting and timeout
  {reply, ok, State#chat_server_state{receivers = [To|Receivers], messages = [Msg|Messages], sent=[Msg|Sent], senders = [From|Senders]}};

handle_call({receive_message,From,To,Msg}, _From, State = #chat_server_state{messages = Messages, received = Received}) ->
  chat_server:receive_message_server(From,To,Msg),
  io:format("i am ~p~n and sent this by ~p",[To, From]),
  {reply, ok, State#chat_server_state{ messages = [Msg|Messages], sent=[Msg|Received] }}.

handle_cast(_Request, State = #chat_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State = #chat_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State = #chat_server_state{}) ->
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State = #chat_server_state{}, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================
```

**without this line %%receive_message(From,To,Msg),**

1.send_message works fine along with send_message_server as below:

```
(bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV)44> chat_client:send_message("bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV","clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV","heee").
message sent!
ok
```

2.receive_message works fine along with receive_message_server as below:

```
(clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV)38> chat_client:receive_message("bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV","clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV","heee").
message received!
I am "clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV"
I received a mesage from "bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV"
ok
```

**Problem:** I already started the chat_server in one node. I need to send a message using one node and at that time, the message should receive to the receiver's node. For that purpose I added the commented line (**receive_message(From,To,Msg)**) inside the send_message's handle_call. It gives  a waiting and timeout (what I wonder here is this worked for its first time I tried,but it did not work again). How to solve this? Error is below.

```
(bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV)38> chat_client:send_message("bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV","clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV","heee").    
message sent!
** exception exit: {timeout,
                       {gen_server,call,
                           [{chat_client,'bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV'},
                            {send_message,"bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV",
                                "clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV","heee"}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 367)
```

After this error when I run any command on receiving node side it gives the frozen result as below,

```
(clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV)5> c(chat_client).                                                                 
message received!
i am "clark@DESKTOP-RD414DV" and sent this by "bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV"
{ok,chat_client}
```

Comment: Sounds like deadlock

Comment: Yes. But I do not understand where it occurs. Waiting for a reply or waiting for another request. Confused!